# Resultado de Query numa outra página

Tags: php, html, sql

Gostaria de saber como eu consigo fazer com que o resultado de uma `query` em uma página minha, preencha uma `tag` em uma outra página;

**Exemplo:**

Eu tenho uma página de pesquisa a quantidade de processos existentes, quando eu clico no botão, vamos supor que ele me retorne 75 como valor.

Quero saber, como eu pego esse 75 (resultado) e coloco numa tag pre que esteja em uma outra página?
Obrigado

Comment: Como assim outra página? Um popup por exemplo ou uma aba aberta como _blank?

Comment: É, o resultado da minha query preencha uma tag de uma página diferente da qual estava

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde!

Você poderia pegar o valor que foi retornado "75", passar via `GET` pra outra pagina, criar a tag desejada e posicionala no HTML com `echo`, ex:

```
<?php
   $var = $_GET['valor']; //valor 75
   $tag = "<h2>$var</h2>";
?>
<html>
<head> 

</head>
<body>
   <?php echo $tag ?> <!-- exibindo 75 em h2 -->
</body>
</html>
```

Nesse exemplo eu usei o "75" pra exibição, mas eu poderia muito bem usar como id, name, height, etc... Ou qualquer outro atributo de tag.

Answer (score 0):

Coloque o valor em uma variável de sessão e carrege a sessão na outra página, ou carregue a outra página com uma query string no endereço da outra página.

Answer (score 0):

Você realizou uma *query* em um arquivo `php`, crie um array e coloque os conteúdos que você quer exibir na página, por exemplo:

```
$data['titulo'] = "Aqui vai o título da página";
```

Coloque os conteúdos que você deseja, é de preferência que o array seja associativo.

Em seguida realize o seguinte:

```
extract($data, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "view");
```

Em que `$data` é o seu `array`, `EXTR_PREFIX_ALL` é uma constante que diz que todas as suas variáveis terão prefixo, e `"view"` é o prefixo que é uma `String` da sua escolha.

Neste caso, dentro do seu código `html`, você deve escrever assim:

```
<p><?php echo $view_titulo; ?></p>
```

Por fim, no seu código `php`, depois do comando `extract` você tem que chamar um:

`require_once "pagina.html";`

Assim funciona comigo.

Esse link do W3Schools pode ajudar: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_extract.asp